# Superclass mismatch for class User (TypeError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have trouble with Heroku.  I did `heroku logs` and got a error message:

```
/app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class User     (TypeError)

/app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class User     (TypeError)

2013-11-28T03:39:50.220378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from    
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in 
`eager_load!'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in 
eager_load!'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 
levels) in eager_load!'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in 
`block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in 
`instance_exec'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in 
`run_initializers'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in 
`initialize!'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in 
`<top (required)>'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block   
in run_initializers'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in 
`method_missing'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in 
`start' 
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.220696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in 
<main>'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from  
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in 
<top (required)>'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top 
(required)>'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-11-28T03:39:50.221093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-11-28T03:39:51.352167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-11-28T03:39:51.375056+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can't understand why I got this error because I have no /models/user.rb/. Yes. I actually made it once and removed it already.

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: did you commit the fact you removed it, and push that change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at

```
/app/app/models/user.rb
```

app/app? This is off. investigate your project source, you do indeed have a user.rb file

Comment: /app is the Heroku root, so /app/app is the app folder of your project.

Comment: Thank you Mr ThelrishGuy, I managed to solve this problem. I just forgot to have some deleted files staged to commit on git. So, I removed deleted files not only on local but on git.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Mr sevenseacat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that this question is not actual for you. But for people who will search for a solution here I'd like just to mention one of possible reasons.
I've got such an error while following "Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl. And in my case it was my inattention - I've placed file **example_user.rb** (from chapter [4.4.5 A user class](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/rails_flavored_ruby#sec-a_user_class)) not in the root directory of application, but in controllers folder. After I've fixed that - that trouble with Heroku disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

For those reading this in the future: here's one potential solution:

#### What is a potential cause?

It is likely, that somewhere in your code, you have defined the same class twice. In this particular case, perhaps the `class User` twice - is defined in two different places. In my particular case, I had the same class and the same file name in two different places in my test code base. Perhaps it is the same situation in your case? It might be worth doing running a quick grep to check. Hope this helps you.