# Superclass mismatch error for User class after using SSL and Puma to deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ssl, heroku

Just tried using SSL in production along with the Puma gemfile for professional grade production but I get an application error when I try to see it live on heroku.

```
 config/environments/production.rb
 .
 .
 # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security,
 # and use secure cookies.
 config.force_ssl = true
 .
 .
```

I'm using gem 'puma','2.11.1' and already did a bundle install.

I also included the following Heroku documentation to make sure things run smoothly:

```
config/puma.rb

workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/
  # deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I aslo created a ./Procfile in the root directory (appears as a file .gitignore, config.ru, and Gemfile if you visualize the layout on Sublime Text).  But for whatever reason it comes out as ".:Procfile" and is hidden with the following:

```
    .:Procfile
    web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

I have also deployed my code with "git push" and "git push heroku master" along with heroku run rake db:migrate and restarted my server but I still see the following applicaton error when I go to my heroku url:

"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.     Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

When looking at my heroku logs I get the following error:

**/app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `': superclass mismatch for class User (TypeError)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255},
                  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Does anyone know what the issue is and how to fix this bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Lets start with the heroku logs- what does it say?
Please run heroku logs -a <app_name> there you should see why application failed-

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I get the following errors with my heroku logs:   heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"

Comment: Hmm, try running `heroku run console` to see maybe you'll get a more detailed error

Comment: Yes, I get the following additional error info when I run that:  /app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class User (TypeError)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257484/superclass-mismatch-for-class-user-typeerror and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22318052/2502605